# File not found | Загрузка файла на диск | PHP | GoogleDriveApi

Tags: php, rest, google-drive

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: xxxx",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: xxxx"
 }
}
```

Есть запрос:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($google);

    $postBody = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => $fileOpt['fileName'],
        'parents' => array(self::$FOLDER_ID)
    ]);

    $content = $service->files->create($postBody, [
        'data' => $fileOpt['data'],
        'mimeType' => 'application/json',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    ]);

    return $content;
```

Даю разрешения:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

Так почему же GoogleApi **не видит папку**, в которую я хочу загрузить файл? Делаю тот же самый запрос через Google **API Explorer** и **работает**!

Request Body Explorer API:

```
"parents": [
    "xxxx"
  ],
  "name": "EXAMPLE_FILE_1",
  "mimeType": "application/json",
  "description": "This is a json file."
```

**Необходимые** разрешения:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

Я в замешательстве. Помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было правильно. Дело не в коде, а в папке. Мне надо было сделать её общедоступной для записи и все заработало. Тем не менее, меня это не устраивает. Если вы знаете, как сделать это без открытия доступа, то жду ответы.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/509092)

Comment: Я дал ответ на свой вопрос. Меня лишь интересует, есть ли другие способы решить мою проблему.

Comment: А как вы теперь узнаете, есть ли другие способы решения или нет? Вы дали ответ и отметили его как решённый. То есть, даже тот, кто возможно знает лучший способ решения, просто ваш вопрос не найдёт, вы его убрали из поиска неотвеченных вопросов. Поэтому, либо как написал в первом комментари, либо задавайте новый вопрос.